# Combining strings in a pandas dataframe works just once in a while-if-elif loop

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have a dataframe with a column (`name`) that contains recurring strings and I want to concatenate values from another column (`reports`) with identicical values in 'name' into one cell.

I thought I'll be getting there with a while-if-elif loop but especially the concatenation only works in the first loop. I just can't figure out why!?

```
#example dataframe
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy', 'Amy', 'Jake'], 
        'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014], 
        'reports': ['Hallo', 'how are', 'you', 'not so', 'foo', 'damn it', 'bar']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['index'] = df.index

#sorting to make the loop work (kept the original index just in case...)
dfSort = df.sort_values(['name'], ascending = True)
dfSort.astype('str')
dfSort.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)

#setting thins up
dfSorted = dfSort.copy()
num = df['name'].count()
i = 0
j = 1
dfNew = dfSorted.loc[:0, :]

#loop
while j < num:
    x = dfSorted.iloc[i:i+1, :1].values
    y = dfSorted.iloc[j:j+1, :1].values
    firstValue = dfSorted.iloc[i:i+1, 2:3].values
    nextValue = dfSorted.iloc[j:j+1, 2:3].values
    print(x, y, firstValue, nextValue, i, j) #just to see what's going on

    if x != y:
        NewRow = dfSorted.iloc[j:j+1, :]
        dfNew = pd.concat([dfNew, NewRow])
        i = j
        j += 1

    elif x == y:
        dfNew.iloc[i:i+1, :] = dfSorted.iloc[i:i+1, :]
        dfNew.iloc[i:i+1, 2:3] = firstValue + ', ' + nextValue

        j += 1
        print('done')#just to see it actually finished the elif-statement
dfNew.head()
```

`dfNew` should have `Amy` with `"foo, damn it"`
and `Jake` with `"not so, bar"` and delete the duplicate rows and keep everything else.
I am sure this is an easy error, but I just don't see it.

Comment: Provide your expected output as well. This most likely doesn''t need a while if else loop. Pandas provides many functions.

Comment: You want `df.groupby(['name', 'year'], as_index=False).agg(', '.join)` probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
dfNew = df.groupby(['name', 'year'], as_index=False)['reports'].agg(list)
dfNew['reports'] = dfNew['reports'].str.join(', ')
```

```py
    name    year    reports
0   Amy     2014    foo, damn it
1   Jake    2014    not so, bar
2   Jason   2012    Hallo
3   Molly   2012    how are
4   Tina    2013    you
```

Comment: YES! Gosh, so easy... Thanks!

Comment: Just that I improve my understanding. Where is the problem in the while loop?

Comment: @MarkusKrohn I'm quite bad at using loops, so probably wouldn't be able to help you with this one. In most cases, though, it's much more efficient to use vectorized functions of pandas library rather than iterating over each row.